# Term for when using a single number is used instead of a function?

Tags: economic-terms

A cost per unit could be `20`, but it could also be `20 + 2q` (in the cast of the latter, the cost per unit is a function whose result increases with each unit produced).

What is the term to describe when a single number is used where we could also expect a function?

I have in mind 'scalar', but I'm not sure if that's the best term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cost function can be **constant** (in $q$), but this term is not particular to economics.

Comment: In this case (cost functions), what do you think of the term 'unit cost'

Comment: I think that unit cost (or rather cost per unit) is something like average cost. Average cost may be constant and may also change, so again I would just say constant average (or constant marginal) cost.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the term you're looking for is **Linear Cost** function?

Comment: But both $C =20$ and $C=20+q$ are linear and the OP seems to want some terminology for the former not for both (although admittedly I am bit confused by the question).

Comment: But he said *cost per unit*. So the first one is linear, the second one is a quadratic cost. But yeah, its kinda confusing.

Comment: oh I did not catch that, my bad.